# What should I do if I asked a question on wrong meta (MSO instead of MSE)?

Tags: discussion, mso-mse-split

What should I do if I asked a question on wrong meta (MSO instead of MSE) post-split; and by the time I realized that it was the wrong meta - meaning the question is about all sites and not SO only - it was already commented on and fully answered on MSO?

- Should I just leave it on MSO?
- Ask a duplicate question on MSE?
- Ask a duplicate question on MSE and link to MSO one?
- Flag for moderators to migrate to MSE? (assuming that's a valid migration path).

*The usual rules about MSO/MSE split doesn't apply here since all the other split-related migration issues that I saw pertained to MSE=>MSO migrations.*

Comment: It'd be meta-ironic if someone points out that THIS question should also have been asked on MSE ...

Comment: Actually, this question should have been asked on **meta.meta**.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Louis http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54973/meta-meta-stackoverflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's already fully answered here on MSO, chances are you can just leave it here. Even if it's not answered, chances are you can just leave it here.

We only migrate questions to the main Meta SE when they need the additional attention from the full network - it's rare that such a migration would even take place. It is perfectly acceptable to ask questions, suggest features, and other things on a per-site Meta - the team still looks at them all.

Answer (score 4):

The same thing you'd do if this happened on any per-site meta: if you realize a post needs to be on MSE because it's important to apply network-wide, use a custom moderator attention flag and ask for it to be migrated. (No need for a migration path; there isn't one. Mods can enter it manually.)

Comment: Is there a formal acknowledgement from mods/SE that it's an **encouraged** type of thing to flag for migration?

Comment: @DVK It's been officially stated that (paraphrasing) "Any meta issues should be posted to the per-site meta you discovered the issue on. If it turns out this is a network-wide issue that needs to be on MSE (previously MSO), it'll get moved." I assume that, if some users get together and decide they think a migration is appropriate, it's reasonable to flag and see what mods think. I know I'd be just fine with seeing a flag like that on my own site.