# How many Stack Exchange sites are there in total?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

I've hovered over the Stack Exchange icon in the top-left corner of the screen from Stack Overflow and this is what I saw:

[image]

I've also hovered over the Stack Exchange icon in the top-left corner of the screen from http://www.stackexchange.com and this is what I saw:

[image]

I manually counted every site from [here](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=grid) and I found out that there are 137 sites.

- How many sites are there in total? 142, 140 or 137 ?
- Why do I find different number of sites in the two tooltips?

Comment: Shouldn't this question be migrated to http://meta.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Apparently, not necessarily http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255291/248065

Comment: This is not the [first time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165241/how-many-stack-exchange-sites-are-there). Or [the second](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214724/how-many-stack-exchange-sites-are-there-really). Or [the third](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251957/difference-in-number-of-communities-on-main-site). In some places private betas are being included in the count.

Comment: @MartijnPieters , I didn't know that! BTW, Your second link redirects me to the first one.

Comment: @CoolGuy: it's a dupe, so it redirects for anon visits. It is also linked in the sidebar from the first, with `?lq=1` appended, so it doesn't redirect: [How many Stack Exchange sites are there really?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214724/how-many-stack-exchange-sites-are-there-really?lq=1)

Comment: @MartijnPieters , So, this means that if I had a MSE account, I can see the duplicate question?

Comment: @CoolGuy: it wouldn't auto-redirect; although there may be a minimum rep requirement. Don't you see the *How many Stack Exchange sites* title in the linked section of the first post?

Comment: @CoolGuy: ah, for anon users it still redirects even when you click on that..

Comment: Better to just say "A list of all stackexchange sites..." forget about the number because then you deal with us anal programmers who will say otherwise.

Comment: This question is the definition of too localised.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reliable way to get those numbers is calling the [/sites](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=500&filter=!6Oe787x*vzH7Z&run=true) endpoint on the Stack API and compensate for the missing Area 51 from that list. That is the total number of sites reported in the site switcher of Stack Exchange.com.

If you run the code snippet you'll get the actual count for each category. When you subtract the number of `closed_beta` from the total, you'll get the number of sites that is available in the Site switcher of the Q/A sites. Notice that the number equals the site databases in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/492050) (but wait for the next Sunday if a site went into beta)

```js
$.get(['https://api.stackexchange.com',
       '2.2',
       'sites'].join('/') + '?pagesize=500&filter=!6Oe787x*vzH7Z', 
      function(data) {
        var states=[], i, j, val, tot = 0; 
        for(i=0; i< data.items.length; i++){
          val = states[data.items[i].site_state];
          if (val == undefined) {
            val =1;
          } else {
            val++;
          }
          states[data.items[i].site_state] = val;
        }
        for(j in states) {
          if (j !== 'linked_meta') {
            tot = tot + states[j];
            $('#site_stat').append(
              $('<tr>').append(
                 $('<td>').text(j), $('<td>').text(states[j])
              ) 
            );
          }
          console.log(j);
          console.log(states[j]);
        }
        $('#site_stat').append(
              $('<tr>').append(
                 $('<td>').text('Area 51'), $('<td>').text('1')
              ) 
            );
         $('#site_stat').append(
              $('<tr>').append(
                 $('<td>').text('total'), $('<td>').text(tot+1)
              ) 
            );
      });
```

```css
td:nth-child(2)
{
  text-align: right;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="site_stat">
  
</table>
```